# NAT not working properly with more LANs - source address is replaced with LAN gateway IP

Tags: networking, router, ip, nat

Running Mikrotik RouterOS, does not matter if version 6.48 or 7.9.

**What works:**

1. Default configuration makes NAT keep source address (i.e. public IP of client which connects to server, chain: input - incoming connections) in IP packets.
2. For 50-50 chance configuring router from scratch for 1 LAN network with mask /24 does not result into this NAT issue/bug/limitation.

**What's the problem with:**

### For incoming connections

(i.e. being established with peers like servers with open ports / port forwarding):

Making **network larger** - 1 LAN network, netmask e.g. /8 and scope 10.0.0.0/8
or
creating from **2** to more **LANs** - e.g. 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.200.0/24

results in *source IP (i.e. client public IP)* being **replaced** with LAN *gateway IP*
while NAT is supposed to keep it unchanged but it seems that RouterOS actually doesn't keep up with that rule.

Noticed in logs on server - web server - that $SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is gateway IP nor client IP visiting a website.

Example configuration with this problem: https://pastebin.com/3Gmxe0SH

Physical connection: ISP router [DMZ onto Mikrotik] -> Indirect LAN connected to WAN port on Mikrotik router [NAT] -> LAN2/Server, LAN1/PC+WiFi

Notice: ISP router connected directly to server works properly (NAT, source address is kept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while NAT is supposed to keep it unchanged but it seems that RouterOS actually doesn't keep up with that rule.

It seems that RouterOS does exactly what your NAT rules specify. What you have in your pastebin is a very broad `action=masquerade` rule without *any* source or destination checks – it **does not tell** RouterOS that some packets should not be SNATed:

```
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat
```

Your srcnat rules need to be selectively applied so that they would only match packets that will be leaving through the WAN interfaces, e.g. using `out-interface=` or `out-interface-list=`.